null hypothesis in ANOVA model formula
I'm working with 2-ways ANOVA. So I am considering the model

Let's imagine each factor has 2 levels.
The overall Null Hypothesis (NH) are:

No effect of factor 1:



No effect of factor 2:



and no effect of the interaction:


I would like to understand how the NHs translate into the model equation. Maybe I am trying an 'arithmetic approach' with the model when I should not.
For example,

If there is no effect of the first factor, does it always mean that α = 0?
And what does it mean that α is zero? for example both α_1 and α_2 may be zero, or α_1 = -2 and α_2 = 2 and then their average is zero? (but then they seem to actually have an effect!, so α would be significant!)
If any of the factors is zero, then the interaction will be always zero as well?
If there is no effect of any factor, then does the model says that each observation is simply the mean plus its own error, right?



If the effect of both factors alone is zero, their interaction must always be zero as well (because either α or β will be zero, thus their multiplication will be zero). However, I've seen cases where the factors are not significant but their interaction is, therefore there must be something wrong with my argument.

In sum, how do I translate the null (and the alternative) hypothesis in terms of the ANOVA model formula?
Finally, if the α and the β of the first equation refer to the average of each group, then shouldn't the model be expressed better as:


A couple things:
First, you use the word "effect" but ANOVA is not necessarily about effects, only relationships. In an observational study, you can't get causality from ANOVA (or other stats).
Second, the overall ANOVA tests one NH, and that is that the F you got from the ANOVA could have arisen in the sample even if there were no relationships in the population. ANOVA programs often display t statistics for each individual variable, and it is possible to get significant t and nonsignificant F. (This actually comes up a lot here).
Third, failing to reject any of the NHs does NOT say there is no effect or that any of the parameters are 0. It just says that there isn't enough evidence against them. Certainly if $\alpha$ or $\beta$ was exactly 0, the product would be. But it is possible to get a significant interaction with no significant main effects.
Finally, there are many ways to write the model.


Finally, if the α and the β of the first equation refer to the average of each group, then shouldn't the model be expressed better as:


This is just a matter of notation.

I would like to understand how the NHs translate into the model equation. Maybe I am trying an 'arithmetic approach' with the model when I should not.
For example,...

That's  a big list of questions. Basically, ANOVA is just comparing two models, but in practice, procedures/functions/algorithms might perform multiple ANOVA's.
The trick behind anova is to consider the $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and compare it to the residuals of a fitted model $r_{ijk}$. Good models tend to reduce the residuals. The statistical test considers whether some reduction in the residuals is beyond expectations when the model is false (quantifying the probability of type I error: considering an effect present while the non-presence of the effect is true).
